# Wordpress Custom Table not updating

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom table I've created in Wordpress that I want to insert a new row and values using a front end form embedded in php code.

When I submit the form, I can see that I've passed the values correctly but the table itself does not update. I'm using a function with a shortcode. I know the table exists and can post the display code if needed. Here's the code for my shortcode:

```
<?php

/*
    Plugin Name: Group Information Updater
    (extra data not included)
*/

function update_group_information_table() {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/user.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/template.php';
 
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'group_information_table';

    // Check if the form is submitted
    if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
        echo '<p>Post request received</p>';
        // Sanitize and validate the input
        $id = intval( $_POST['id'] );
        $groupid = intval( $_POST['groupid'] );
        $group_user_role = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['group_user_role'] );
        $forum_id = intval( $_POST['forum_id'] );

        echo '<p>' . $id . ' ' . $groupid . ' ' . $group_user_role . ' ' . $forum_id . '</p>';
        // Update the database
        $wpdb->insert(
            $table_name,
            array( 'group_name' => $id, 'group_id' => $groupid, 'group_name' => $group_user_role, 'forum_id' => $forum_id,) // Data to update
        );

        echo '<div>Group Information Updated</div>';
    }

    // Display the form
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td><label for="id">ID:</label></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="id" id="id" required></td>
    
            <td><label for="groupid">GID:</label></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="groupid" id="groupid" required></td>

            <td><label for="group_user_role">User Role:</label></td>
            <?php echo '<td><select name="group_user_role" id="group_user_role">';
                  echo wp_dropdown_roles(); ?>
                </select></td>

            <td><label for="forum_id">Forum ID:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="forum_id" id="forum_id" required></td>
            </tr>    

            <tr>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Group">
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
    <?php
}

// Shortcode to display the form
function group_info_form_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    update_group_information_table();
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('group_info_form', 'group_info_form_shortcode');
```

When I run the code, I get a Group Information Updated message. However, when I display the table, only the one existing record is included.

Comment: Your insert statement lists the `group_name` column twice. Try coding with safety checks. Use try/catch. Evaluate the return value from the call to [$wpdb->insert()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/). Log values from [$wpdb->last_error](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#properties). Use the $wpdb->insert() [$format](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/#parameters) parameter to map data types.

Comment: If you are including code that can modify the database via a shortcode, you should strongly consider adding a [nonce](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/security/nonces/#adding-a-nonce-to-a-form)

Comment: Thank you! The group_name was the source of the problem. I also very much appreciate the advice to use try/catch and evaluate the log values, which caught another hidden issue in the code.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Now that it's working, I'm adding the nonce as you suggested. It wasn't required while I was working on the staging site but definitely don't want to put it into production without nonce.